# How to format cells in a joined table?

Tags: pandas, number-formatting

Both tables that I merge have the cells formatted correctly, as numbers, but when I make a left join, the numbers in one of the original tables get dis-formatted (you see e+ in those numbers). What should I do to see those numbers un full?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem: When merging, some SKU values that appear in df1 do not appear in df2. In order to represent unavailable values, pandas automatically uses `NaN`, which is a floating point value. Thus, the integer ISBNs are converted to float. Given the size of the ISBNs, pandas then formats these floating point values in scientific notation.

You could solve this by defining your own floating point value formatter (`pd.options.display.float_format`), but in your case it might be easier / more effective to convert the ISBNs to a string before merging.

Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"SKU": list("abcde"), "ISBN": list(range(1, 6))})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"SKU": list("bcef"), "ISBN": list(range(4, 8))})
```

Your problem:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on="SKU", how="left")
  SKU  ISBN_x  ISBN_y
0   a       1     NaN
1   b       2     4.0
2   c       3     5.0
3   d       4     NaN
4   e       5     6.0
>>> _.dtypes
SKU        object
ISBN_x      int64
ISBN_y    float64 # <<< Problematic
```

vs possible solution:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1.astype(str), df2.astype(str), on="SKU", how="left")
  SKU ISBN_x ISBN_y
0   a      1    NaN
1   b      2      4
2   c      3      5
3   d      4    NaN
4   e      5      6
>>> _.dtypes
SKU       object
ISBN_x    object
ISBN_y    object
```